# How to make a link that randomize a group of links when clicked?

Tags: javascript

I tried this code from a certain website....

```
function randomlinks(){

var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*9)
var links=new Array()

links[0]="http://www.javascriptkit.com"
links[1]="http://www.dynamicdrive.com"
links[2]="http://www.cssdrive.com"
links[3]="http://www.codingforums.com"
links[4]="http://www.news.com"
links[5]="http://www.gamespot.com"
links[6]="http://www.msnbc.com"
links[7]="http://www.cnn.com"
links[8]="http://news.bbc.co.uk"
links[9]="http://www.news.com.au"
window.location=links[myrandom]
}
```

```
<form>

    <input type="button" value="random link!" onClick="randomlinks()">

</form>
```

it works very well...
i changed `<form>` part to

```
<form>

  <input type="image" src="img.jpg" value="random link!" onClick="randomlinks()">

</form>
```

it didn't work.
please help me find out why!
thank you..i'll wait

Comment: input type image is used to submit the data of a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input type `image` is used to submit the data of a form.

```js
function randomlinks(){

var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*9);
var links=new Array();

links[0]="http://www.javascriptkit.com";
links[1]="http://www.dynamicdrive.com";
links[2]="http://www.cssdrive.com";
links[3]="http://www.codingforums.com";
links[4]="http://www.news.com";
links[5]="http://www.gamespot.com";
links[6]="http://www.msnbc.com";
links[7]="http://www.cnn.com";
links[8]="http://news.bbc.co.uk";
links[9]="http://www.news.com.au";
window.location=links[myrandom];
}
```

```html
 <img style="width:48px" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-8/256/Insert-hyperlink-icon.png" value="random link!" onclick="randomlinks()">
```

Lose the form and just attach the onclick handler to the image.

Also: avoid DynamicDrive (*It's the source of all evil in this world*, like snowflakes scripts). And make it a habit of closing your lines with a `;`

Comment: @JohnCarlRondesYmas, Nope that's logical, needs to be on your server :-). Updated it with a working image link.

Comment: i changed the "src link" but still displayed the word "random link!"

Comment: ooooohhh! i got it! Thank You so much!

Have a nice day...

by the way...its my first time to post here :)

Comment: help me...i dont know how...i tried the arrow up but it said to have at least 15 rep. :(

Comment: @JohnCarlRondesYmas There's a `V` underneath my answer's voting buttons, you can press it.